# Saving Data from External Server to Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am fairly new to Parse and am looking to save data to Parse.com which are located in .csv files from an external server I have access to be consumed by an android app that I am currently writing. I have been searching for the tools that I would need to do this on Parse.com but I am a little lost right now. If someone could push me in the right direction that would be extremely helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to import just once or you have to import as your app activity? If the first one is your case, you can use Parse.com import tool.

http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/22/import-your-csv-data-to-parse/

For other case, there are many other alternatives, please explain more about your application.

---

**EDIT AS PER IN COMMENT:** PHP SDK Use Case

1. You can use PHP built-in function like http://php.net/fgetcsv to read through the CSV files.
2. Then you should use Parse.Object.saveAll function to batch saving to Parse backend. (http://parseplatform.github.io/parse-php-sdk/classes/Parse.ParseObject.html#method_saveAll)

Comment: My backend data gets updated everyday and I want to update the current data on Parse with this new data every time the backend data gets updated. My idea right now is to write a PHP script to read in these csv files and use cronjob to do this at a certain time every day.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with PHP built-in function like http://php.net/fgetcsv. Then you should use Parse.Object.saveAll function to batch saving to Parse backend. (http://parseplatform.github.io/parse-php-sdk/classes/Parse.ParseObject.html#method_saveAll)

Answer (score 0):

**KEEPING EVERYTHING INSIDE PARSE**

I figured out a way to do this without having to write a PHP script but instead using background jobs and cloud code.

1. Parse provides their own implementation of http request https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.html#methods_httpRequest
2. Using this, you can use your link to your csv located on an external server and now you can manipulate the csv.
3. I used Papa Parse to parse through my csv file and do what I needed with it http://papaparse.com/
4. To use Papa Parse, you must include it as a module by placing the papaparse.js file inside your cloud directory and initializing it by `var papa = require('cloud/papaparse.js');` inside your `main.js`
5. Now by looking at Papa Parse's documents, you can do whatever you need to the csv
6. Set this code as a background job and you're finished.

I hope this helps.